# How can I check if the values of one dictionary partially match to the values of another dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm very new to programming so please forgive my ignorance.

As practice, I'm trying to write a Python program that has a dictionary of musical scales and a dictionary of chords. The keys in these dictionaries are the names of the scales/chords, whereas the values are the notes that these scales/chords consist of.

I've tried looking for an answer to this, but so far I've only been able to find situations where the values of dictionaries are compared to see whether they are equal or not. I want to see if the value of one dictionary is part of the value of another dictionary, and if so, I want the program to show me these values along with the keys they belong to.

```
scales = {'major': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 
          'harmmaj': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'b6', '7'],
          'minor': ['1', '2', 'b3', '4', '5', 'b6', 'b7'],
          'harmmin': ['1', '2', 'b3', '4', '5', 'b6', '7'],
          'melmin': ['1', '2', 'b3', '4', '5', '6', '7']}

chords = {'minor': ['1', 'b3', '5'],
        'm6': ['1', 'b3', '5', '6'],
        'm7': ['1', 'b3', '5', 'b7'],
        'sus2': ['1', '2', '5'],
        'sus4': ['1', '4', '5'],
        'maj': ['1', '3', '5'],
        'maj6': ['1', '3', '5', '6'],
        'maj7': ['1', '3', '5', '7'],
        'dom7': ['1', '3', '5', 'b7'],
        'dim': ['1', 'b3', 'b5'],
        'dim7': ['1', 'b3', 'b5', 'b7'],
        'aug': ['1', '3', '#5'],
        'aug7': ['1', '3', '#5', 'b7']}
```

I know how to do this with two strings:

```
minor = ['1', '2', 'b3', '4', '5', 'b6', 'b7']
m7 = ['1', 'b3', '5', 'b7']
foundmatches = []

for i in range(len(m7)):
    if m7[i] in minor:
        foundmatches.append(m7[i])

print(foundmatches)
```

But am very lost on how to do this with two dictionaries. I've tried looping through both dictionaries and doing the following:

```
for value in range(len(chords)):
    for value in range(len(scales)):
        if chords[value] in scales[value]:
            print(chords[value])
```

This gives me a KeyError and is honestly probably a dumb way of trying to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you might be looking for [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) here, in particular `<=` to see whether a set is the subset of another (whether a chord is the subset of a scale):

```
scales = {
    "harmmaj": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "b6", "7"],
    "harmmin": ["1", "2", "b3", "4", "5", "b6", "7"],
    "major": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
    "melmin": ["1", "2", "b3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
    "minor": ["1", "2", "b3", "4", "5", "b6", "b7"],
}

chords = {
    "minor": ["1", "b3", "5"],
    "m6": ["1", "b3", "5", "6"],
    "m7": ["1", "b3", "5", "b7"],
    "sus2": ["1", "2", "5"],
    "sus4": ["1", "4", "5"],
    "maj": ["1", "3", "5"],
    "maj6": ["1", "3", "5", "6"],
    "maj7": ["1", "3", "5", "7"],
    "dom7": ["1", "3", "5", "b7"],
    "dim": ["1", "b3", "b5"],
    "dim7": ["1", "b3", "b5", "b7"],
    "aug": ["1", "3", "#5"],
    "aug7": ["1", "3", "#5", "b7"],
}

for chord_name, chord_spec in chords.items():
    chord_spec_set = set(chord_spec)
    for scale_name, scale_spec in scales.items():
        if chord_spec_set <= set(scale_spec):
            print(chord_name, "is in", scale_name)
```

This prints out (in some order)

```
m6 is in melmin
m7 is in minor
maj is in harmmaj
maj is in major
maj6 is in major
maj7 is in harmmaj
maj7 is in major
minor is in harmmin
minor is in melmin
minor is in minor
sus2 is in harmmaj
sus2 is in harmmin
sus2 is in major
sus2 is in melmin
sus2 is in minor
sus4 is in harmmaj
sus4 is in harmmin
sus4 is in major
sus4 is in melmin
sus4 is in minor
```

Comment: Great, thank you! So do I understand correctly that if I want to check if the value of one dictionary is part of a value of another dictionary, I should always use set operations, because these operations can't be used directly on dictionaries?

Comment: You have 2 dictionaries which both contain string keys and list values. You can't directly convert a dictionary into a set, since a set does not map keys to values.